# Nginx permissions question

Tags: permissions, nginx

I have nginx + spawn cgi and php set,
nginx and spawn cgi run as nobody, my web files are in folder that root created
and now i get "403 Forbidden" error and thats probably because of permissions,
should i add new user and group and put files there and run nginx etc with that user?
if so what permissions should i set?

Answer (score 2):

That's probably because of absence of `index.php`/`index.html` files in root directory